# Import DXF blocks from one file to another using GDAL

Tags: c++, gdal, dxf

I'm working on a CAD program with the GDAL library version 1.11.4.

I have two DXF files: `a.dxf` and `b.dxf`. `a.dxf` is a template file. The file has a block layer. It contains some features (symbol information). `b.dxf` contains some point coordinates. I should display the points (`b.dxf`) using the symbols (`a.dxf`).

My thoughts: export the blocks from `a.dxf` and import them into `b.dxf`.

But `b.dxf` can't open on the CAD. Hers is my code:

```
enter code here
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "ogrsf_frmts.h"  
#include "gdal.h"
#include "stdio.h"  

int main()
{
    const char *pszDriverName = "DXF";
    OGRSFDriver *poDriver = nullptr;

    RegisterOGRDXF();

    CPLSetConfigOption("GDAL_DATA", "./debug/data");
    CPLSetConfigOption("DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS", "false");


    poDriver = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::GetRegistrar()->GetDriverByName("DXF");
    if (poDriver == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s driver not available.\n", pszDriverName);
        exit(1);
    }

    OGRDataSource* poDS = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::Open("a.dxf", true, &poDriver);
    //the block layer
    OGRLayer* blockLayer = poDS->GetLayer(0);
    OGRFeature* copy = blockLayer->GetFeature(0);

    OGRDataSource* poDS1 = poDriver->CreateDataSource("b.dxf");
    OGRLayer* blockLayer1 = poDS1->CreateLayer("blocks");
    OGRLayer* entityLayer1 = poDS1->CreateLayer("entites");
    auto err1 = blockLayer1->CreateFeature(copy);

    OGRFeature::DestroyFeature(copy);

    OGRDataSource::DestroyDataSource(poDS);
    OGRDataSource::DestroyDataSource(poDS1);
}
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem. add {copy->SetFID(1)}, the fid equals zero default. i don't know why.